# android studio, there is no import non android-studio project option

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image: in here]

I want to import an project that is not made with android studio. There should be a option like "import non android-studio project" but there isn't.

When I try to import it via the "Import project (Eclipse SDT, Gradle, etc.)" option, [it says this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwZff.png)

Comment: Android Studio is just a stripped-down version of IntelliJ IDEA.  If you want to work on Android projects that were developed in another IDE, use the import feature as Jack suggests.  But if you want to work on non-Android projects, use IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 3):

The `Import project(Eclipse,ADT,Gradle,etc.)` option is there. It does exactly what you need!

Comment: Does the import feature convert the project to Android Studio format, or does it retain the original file structure and build script?

Comment: It changes the structure, but you will have different options on how you want to see the project structure

Comment: Did you start it as a java project in eclipse? It won't work that way! If you didn't start like this - https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/get-started-developing-for-android-with-eclipse/  then start a new android project and copy-paste all your files in android project. They 'll work fine!